# How to add animation in bottomsheet when changes its state

Tags: android, animation, bottom-sheet, android-bottomsheetdialog

My app contain a bottomsheeet and i am using following methods to change its state

```
 public void toggleBottomSheet() {
    if (sheetBehavior.getState() != BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
        sheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
    } else {
        sheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
    }
}
```

But in some devices it is not showing animation properly ( Bottom to up ), It opens directly like popup. 
How to add animation so it looks it is coming from bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this point of **"in some devices"**, can you please mention the android version and other specifications? My suggestion is to add a BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback to the BottomSheetBehavior

and in its onSlide method put a log.d() to check if its really sliding. It will help to find out the cause. Also, make sure that you have added the right BootmSheetBehavior and you can try by setting the **peeckHeight** explicitly.

```
  yourBottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View view, int newState)
        {
            if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED)
            {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View view, float v)
        {
            Log.d("tag", "sliding from bottom to top");

        }
    });
```

Comment: "in some devices" android 6.0

Comment: Peek Height is working and its STATE_COLLAPSED and STATE_EXPANDED is also working but it is not coming with animation from bottom to top. It is showing popup in some devices like 6.0